# jQuery set up after npm install

Tags: jquery, npm

i am running `npm install jquery --save-dev` from the command prompt to installing jquery for my project. but when i am using jquery from my javascript file it always returns the error:'$ is not defined'.
I am following the install instruction from https://jquery.com/download/.
but if i run `$`from chrome console it works fine.

I am wondering did i just missed some important setup from my package.json file?

Answer (score 2):

This usually indicates that jQuery is not loaded and JavaScript does not recognize `$`. Are you trying to run this code locally, on your own machine? If so, you will need to add a script tag before your script.js and load jQuery from a CDN:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>`

Regarding the javascript file, you are asking about then you can add one of the below lines as per your framework syntax to create a reference to `$` from already installed npm package.

`import $ from "jquery";`

Or

`var $ = require("jquery");`

You can also refer the official package docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Hi Suhas, thanks for your answer, i was thought install jquery via NPM would be a super convenient and one step method without downloading all the jquery.min files.

Comment: But i found the jquery.min.js file in the node_modules and i am fixing that with adding '<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>' at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @JianNCI, I have tried this, but its not working. Can someone help me to get this working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71714891/how-to-use-jquery-libraries-on-a-project-with-npm?noredirect=1#comment126741453_71714891

Comment: It's likely your node_modules directory is a parent to the public directory, so by adding it as descibed above to your main app.,js will work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to point to the jQuery file in `node_modules`, then dist.

Answer (score 0):

and add this code in your HTML file

```
<script type='module' src='./fileLocation'></script>
```