# How to use jQuery libraries on a project with npm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm

I'm trying jQuery for the first time, I know this library is becoming more and more unused, but I need it to work with it on a project.

So I initialized a jQuery project with `npm install jquery`, so node modules and package-lock.json were created. I wonder how should I target library files on the index.html file, I mean maybe it should be something like this `<script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Also how should I use libraries on `.js` files.

I don't know if I should point file by file or how should I use library files. Maybe someone could guide me with examples or docs on how to start using a jQuery libraries on a project.

Comment: There are a variety of ways to handle package management for client side apps using npm … what you do after installing jQuery that way really depends on what method you've picked. So how are you using modules from npm elsewhere in your project? And if you aren't, why are you using npm to download jQuery?

Comment: @Quentin, I'm also using bootstrap5. I used npm to install jQuery since I didn't want to use CDNs, because this seems to be better when developing a whole project

Answer (score 1):

In your relevant javascript files (where you need to use jQuery) you should be doing

`import $ from "jquery";`

at the top. Also install and configure babel for compiling as it will
support ES6/ES2015 modules even if browsers do not yet support.

Comment: I have some questions about. First, do I have to use <script src="./node_modules/jquery/src/jquery.js"></script> on index.html file?. Just for trying what you suggested, I code this on Script.js file import $ from "jquery"; $(() => alert("WORKING");});. But I'm getting the error below on browser console so it is not working.

Comment: This error is related to Script.js file that is also linked on index.html file: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at Script.js:1:1)